# unable to auto increment session value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, session

In my wordpress project i want to run a mysql query in thank you page when user is redirected to it only once a time. But when user refresh it, it should not run. I created a session variable and did the below way. But it did not work. Can somebody help me.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['countval']=0;

if($_SESSION['countval']==0){

     $wpdb->insert('wp_user_points',
                   array('user_id' =>$current_user->ID , 
                         'order_id'=>$order_id,
                         'product_sku' =>$new_sku,
                         'pv'=>$points,
                         'added_on'=>date("Y-m-d  H:i:s"),
                         'payment_method'=>$order->payment_method_title,
                         'payment_statues'=>'pending'
                        )
                  );
     $_SESSION['countval']++;

}
```

Comment: isnt this (`$_SESSION['countval']=0;`) always makes this 0

Comment: so if i will not assign value to session will it work?

Comment: i think you need to set only once(depends on what you want to do) .. btw you can try what DevZer0 is saying since i think its pretty much what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set `$_SESSION['countval']=0;` in first line. 
Use this code:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['countval']))
   $_SESSION['countval']=0;

if($_SESSION['countval']==0){

     $wpdb->insert('wp_user_points',
                   array('user_id' =>$current_user->ID , 
                         'order_id'=>$order_id,
                         'product_sku' =>$new_sku,
                         'pv'=>$points,
                         'added_on'=>date("Y-m-d  H:i:s"),
                         'payment_method'=>$order->payment_method_title,
                         'payment_statues'=>'pending'
                        )
                  );
     $_SESSION['countval']++;
   }
```

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Sorry,I just copy from question. ;)

Comment: please dont apologize ..if answer is helpful than its cool .. and i was just kidding  :)

Comment: It's still the same. the query works when i refresh the page. But thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Ok. I tried with an another approach. First i checked whether there is an order number equal to current order number in the table. If so i don't run the query and if not i run the query. That worked. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

you seems to be resetting your counter every time. instead of having this line of code
`$_SESSION['countval']=0;`

make sure you only set it one time by testing to see if its already set.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['countval'])) $_SESSION['countval']=0;
```